# Can't set adapter of ListView because the ListView has a null object reference

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment, onresume

I am trying to make a TabLayout with a ViewPager, but whenever I leave the app (Don't close it, just switch to another app and back) the fragments kind of get killed. I don't know that for sure, but the fragment's need to reCreate, and then fail.

The code for creating the TabLayout, TabLayoutAdapter and the ViewPager:

```
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);     
    MyTabLayoutAdapter tabLayoutAdapter;
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("-2"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("-1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("0"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("2"));

    tabLayoutAdapter = new MyTabLayoutAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(tabLayoutAdapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
```

The code of my TabLayoutAdapter:

```
public class MyTabLayoutAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private MyFragment fragmentOne;
    private MyFragment fragmentTwo;
    private MyFragment fragmentDefault;
    private MyFragment fragmentFour;
    private MyFragment fragmentFive;
    private int numberOfTabs;

    public MyTabLayoutAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, int numberOfTabs) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        fragmentOne = new MyFragment();
        fragmentTwo = new MyFragment();
        fragmentDefault = new MyFragment();
        fragmentFour = new MyFragment();
        fragmentFive = new MyFragment();
        this.numberOfTabs = numberOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public MyFragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return fragmentOne;
            case 1:
                return fragmentTwo;
            case 2:
                return fragmentDefault;
            case 3:
                return fragmentFour;
            case 4:
                return fragmentFive;
            default:
                return fragmentDefault;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numberOfTabs;
    }
}
```

The MyFragment fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private View currentView;
    private ListView listView;

    public MyFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        currentView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_layout, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) currentView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        return currentView;
    }

    //This line throws a NullPointer when I resume the app
    public void populateListView(MyListAdapter myListAdapter) {
        listView.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
    }
}
```

Whenever I call

```
MyListAdapter myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.my_item, justSomeStringArray);
tabLayoutAdapter.getItem(0).populateListView(myListAdapter);
```

I get a NullPointerException saying that it can't set a adapter on a null object reference.

Anyone any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach which lets the Fragment instance drive the data retrieval by using an AsyncTask implementation (GetDataForListViewTask).

But, to follow Commonsware's advice, GetDataForListViewTask merely obtains the data. It does not set up the adapter for use on the ListViews. Instead, setting up the ListAdapter is done in the Fragment itself.

GetDataForListViewTask passes the data back to the Fragment instance using EventBus. This keeps GetDataForListViewTask from having to maintain a reference to the ListView, Activity, Context or any of that risky stuff.

And, by not "reaching in" to a Fragment from the outside to change its widgets or even hand it data, this code also tries (very broadly) to follow another piece of CommonsWare's guidance:

> In general, having code outside of a fragment attempt to manipulate
>   the widgets inside that fragment — as you are doing here — is a bad
>   idea.

In any case, if you use this approach, which is a bit different from your original approach, you'll want to modify the GetDataForListViewTask so that it obtains the data from elsewhere in your app or the network, etc.

**GetDataForListViewTask.java**

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus;
import java.util.ArrayList;


class GetDataForListViewTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... ignored) {
        // since this method runs on a worker thread, you may
        // replace this code with a network call or a background computation
        // from another part of the app is ready
        ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            listItems.add("item " + i);
        }

        return listItems;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        // post event so that Fragment can use the data to populate its ListView
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new MyFragment.ListViewDataReadyEvent(result));
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        MyAdapter tabLayoutAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 5);
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabLayoutAdapter);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
    }

    class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private final int count;

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int count) {
            super(fm);
            this.count = count;
        }

        @Override
        public MyFragment getItem(int position) {
            return MyFragment.newInstance();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.count;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Tab " + position;
        }
    }

}
```

**MyFragment.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus;
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe;
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

        private ListView listView;
        private GetDataForListViewTask getDataForListViewTask;

        public static MyFragment newInstance() {
            return new MyFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setRetainInstance(true); // to support use of GetDataForListViewTask
            EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            listView = (ListView) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.my_fragment_layout, container, false);
            getDataForListViewTask = new GetDataForListViewTask();
            getDataForListViewTask.execute();
            return listView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            if (getDataForListViewTask != null) {
                getDataForListViewTask.cancel(false);
            }
            EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        static class ListViewDataReadyEvent {

            ArrayList<String> data;
            ListViewDataReadyEvent(ArrayList<String> data) {
                this.data = data;
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
        public void onMessageEvent(ListViewDataReadyEvent event) {
            if (listView != null) {
                ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(listView.getContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, event.data.toArray(new String[]{}));
                listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            }
        }
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="4dip"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

**my_fragment_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</ListView>
```

**Selected compile statements for build.gradle**

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

`onCreateView()` is not called on a fragment until the fragment is being added to a `FragmentManager`. Your final code snippet will only work, at best, if it is called sometime after `fragmentOne` is added to a `FragmentManager`. Otherwise, the fragment's `ListView` will not exist yet.

In general, having code *outside* of a fragment attempt to manipulate the widgets *inside* that fragment — as you are doing here — is a bad idea.

Comment: Well.. I have a http request at the background, and when I get a response, I try to create the ListAdapter and add it. The weird part is that I make a call to the http request after the TabLayout and everything is set up. Is there a possibility to check if the fragment is added to the FragmentManager?

Comment: @Jason: "I have a http request at the background, and when I get a response, I try to create the ListAdapter and add it" -- it is not the job of the networking code to set up a `ListAdapter`. It is the job of the networking code to get the data and make it available to the UI. In your case, the UI is not yet ready for the data, but the UI can arrange to hold onto that data until such time as it is called with `onCreateView()` to make use of the data.

Comment: So you are telling me to create the ListAdapter in the constructor of the fragment, and add the adapter to the listView in the onCreate?

Comment: @Jason: "So you are telling me to create the ListAdapter in the constructor of the fragment" -- no, as you do not have access to the activity yet, and so you cannot create a `ListAdapter`. I am telling you to *give the data to the fragment* (e.g., `tabLayoutAdapter.getItem(0).pleaseHaveSomeData(whatever);`), and let the fragment create the `ListAdapter` when appropriate. That could be immediately (if the `ListView` is already created), or that could be in `onViewCreated()` (if the `ListView` is not yet created).

Comment: Whenever the http request is ready, I call a method that saves the contents and context. In the onCreateView, I make an adapter and add it to the listview. It does not seem to work at all..

Comment: The question would rather be: Why does it only happen when I switch to another application, and then back?

Comment: @Jason: Your process can be terminated at any point while your app is in the background. Upon returning to the app, a fresh process is forked, and a fresh activity and fragments are created. Whether that is the source of your difficulty, I cannot say.